# Vuex getter for each item

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to figure out a way to add a computed property for each item an array in a Vuex store. For example, in a Todo list application, each Todo item may have DueDate and a Completed flag. Based on these properties we can compute if the Todo item is overdue.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        Todos: []
    },
    mutations: { /* ... */ },
    actions: {/* ... */ } 
);

let exampleTodo = {
    Title: 'Go grocery shopping',
    Completed: false,
    DueDate: new Date("10/12/2017")
};
```

So far I've been adding the computed property at the component level using `mapState` like this:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState({
        todos: state => state.Todos.map(t => {
            // Add some computed fields
            return {
                ...t,
                OverDue: !t.Completed && Date.now() > t.DueDate
            };
        })
    })
}
```

But this means the calculation needs to be implemented for each component. For something this simple it's not a big deal, but for more complex calculations I'd rather have them in one place. Is there a way to accomplish this in the store, or should I keep using this pattern? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a `getter` to do the mapping in the Vuex store. The getter function will be run (and its returned value cached) the first time it is accessed. Any subsequent references to that getter will return the cached value, unless the dependant state is updated, in which case the getter function will be run again.

[Here's the documentation on Vuex getters.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html)

Here's an example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: []
  },
  mutations: { 
    SET_TODOS(state, todos) {
      state.todos = todos;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    todos(state) {
      return state.todos.map(t => {
        return {
          ...t,
          OverDue: !t.Completed && Date.now() > t.DueDate
        }
      })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  created() {
    let todos = [{
      Title: 'Go grocery shopping',
      Completed: false,
      DueDate: new Date("10/12/2017")
    }, {
      Title: 'Get a haircut',
      Completed: false,
      DueDate: new Date("10/10/2017")
    }];
    
    this.$store.commit('SET_TODOS', todos)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ $store.getters.todos }}
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that seems so obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: @thanksd Is OverDue reactive / computed if DueDate changes? If so great, if not I'd be curious to see how that could be done.

Comment: I wonder how best to extract OverDue and the like into a separate object definition. If there are several methods, the todos getter would quickly get crowded.

Comment: @btd, OverDue will reactively update if DueDate changes, yes. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/zeLgkk2e/. Not sure what you mean by "a separate object definition".